# 1 second timer activating multiple times a second

Tags: java

trying to make a cookie clicker style game in java.
I'm a beginner, so it's bad...
here is what I have:

```
static double money = 50;
static double mps = 0; //money per second

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    
    
    System.out.println("\n*You have $50*"
    + "\n*Use this money to make more money*"
    + "\n*Type \"stats\" To see what you can buy*");
    
    String statsString = "*Type Numbers To Buy, You Can Only Buy If You Have Enough Money!*"
            + "\n1 = $50 = 1 $/sec"
            + "\n2 = $100 = 2.2 $/sec"
            + "\n3 = $300 = 7.2 $/sec"
            + "\n4 = $1,200 = 31.2 $/sec"
            + "\n5 = $6,000 = 168 $/sec"
            + "\n6 = $36,000 = 1,080 $/sec"
            + "\n7 = $253,000 = 5,060 $/sec"
            + "\n8 = $2,024,000 = 68,816 $/sec"
            + "\n9 = $18,216,000 = 6 $/sec";
    
    
    while (true) {

    String input;
    try {

        Scanner stats = new  Scanner(System.in);

        input = stats.next();
        
        if(input.matches("stats")){ //if user inputs "stats", print stats
            System.out.println(statsString);
            
        } else if(input.matches("1") && money >= 50) { //if user inputs 1 and has 50+ money, buy one, subtract 50 from money and add 1 to money per second
       
            money = money - 50;
            mps = mps + 1;
            System.out.println(current money per second is " + mps);
            
        } else if(input.matches("2") && money >= 100) { //same as last comment, but different numbers
            
            money = money - 100;
            mps = mps + 2.20;
            System.out.println(current money per second is " + mps);
            
        } else if(input.matches("3") && money >= 300) { //same as last comment, but different numbers
            
            money = money - 300;
            mps = mps + 7.20;
            System.out.println(current money per second is " + mps);
            
        } else if(input.matches("4") && money >= 1200) { //same as last comment, but different numbers
            
            money = money - 1200;
            mps = mps + 31.20;
            System.out.println(current money per second is " + mps);
            
        } else if(input.matches("5") && money >= 6000) { //same as last comment, but different numbers
            
            money = money - 6000;
            mps = mps + 168;
            System.out.println(current money per second is " + mps);
            
        } else if(input.matches("6") && money >= 36000) { //same as last comment, but different numbers
            
            money = money - 36000;
            mps = mps + 1080;
            System.out.println(current money per second is " + mps);
            
        } else if(input.matches("7") && money >= 253000) { //same as last comment, but different numbers
            
            money = money - 253000;
            mps = mps +5060;
            System.out.println(current money per second is " + mps);
            
        } else if(input.matches("8") && money >= 2024000) { //same as last comment, but different numbers
            
            money = money - 2024000;
            mps = mps + 68816;
            System.out.println(current money per second is " + mps);
            
        } else if(input.matches("9") && money >= 18216000) { //same as last comment, but different numbers
            
            money = money - 18216000;
            mps = mps + 655776;
            System.out.println(current money per second is " + mps);
            
        } else{ //if none of the above inputs are input, say something is wrong, either not enough money or not a chosen valid input
            System.out.println("you don't have enough money for that!");
        }//end else

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }//end catch 
    
    
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            
            System.out.println("You have $" + money + "!");
            money = money + mps;
                            
        }//end public void run
    }, 0, 1000);//timer task
    }//end while true loop
}//end string
```

Every time one of the else if statements works, instead of outputting money every second, it does it twice every second, then if another else if statement works, three money output per second...
essentially, the money per second increases more than every second every time I press 1-9.

Answer (score 0):

Right now a new timer task is started every time a user buys an item. If you moved your task timer above your while loop it ensure only a single timer is executing.

```
    static double money = 50;
    static double mps = 0; //money per second

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{


        System.out.println("\n*You have $50*"
                + "\n*Use this money to make more money*"
                + "\n*Type \"stats\" To see what you can buy*");

        String statsString = "*Type Numbers To Buy, You Can Only Buy If You Have Enough Money!*"
                + "\n1 = $50 = 1 $/sec"
                + "\n2 = $100 = 2.2 $/sec"
                + "\n3 = $300 = 7.2 $/sec"
                + "\n4 = $1,200 = 31.2 $/sec"
                + "\n5 = $6,000 = 168 $/sec"
                + "\n6 = $36,000 = 1,080 $/sec"
                + "\n7 = $253,000 = 5,060 $/sec"
                + "\n8 = $2,024,000 = 68,816 $/sec"
                + "\n9 = $18,216,000 = 6 $/sec";


        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("You have $" + money + "!");
                money = money + mps;

            }//end public void run
        }, 0, 1000);//timer task
        while (true) {

            String input;
            try {

                Scanner stats = new  Scanner(System.in);

                input = stats.next();

                if(input.matches("stats")){ //if user inputs "stats", print stats
                    System.out.println(statsString);

                } else if(input.matches("1") && money >= 50) { //if user inputs 1 and has 50+ money, buy one, subtract 50 from money and add 1 to money per second

                    money = money - 50;
                    mps = mps + 1;
                    System.out.println("current money per second is " + mps);

                } else if(input.matches("2") && money >= 100) { //same as last comment, but different numbers

                    money = money - 100;
                    mps = mps + 2.20;
                    System.out.println("current money per second is " + mps);

                } else if(input.matches("3") && money >= 300) { //same as last comment, but different numbers

                    money = money - 300;
                    mps = mps + 7.20;
                    System.out.println("current money per second is " + mps);

                } else if(input.matches("4") && money >= 1200) { //same as last comment, but different numbers

                    money = money - 1200;
                    mps = mps + 31.20;
                    System.out.println("current money per second is " + mps);

                } else if(input.matches("5") && money >= 6000) { //same as last comment, but different numbers

                    money = money - 6000;
                    mps = mps + 168;
                    System.out.println("current money per second is " + mps);

                } else if(input.matches("6") && money >= 36000) { //same as last comment, but different numbers

                    money = money - 36000;
                    mps = mps + 1080;
                    System.out.println("current money per second is " + mps);

                } else if(input.matches("7") && money >= 253000) { //same as last comment, but different numbers

                    money = money - 253000;
                    mps = mps +5060;
                    System.out.println("current money per second is " + mps);

                } else if(input.matches("8") && money >= 2024000) { //same as last comment, but different numbers

                    money = money - 2024000;
                    mps = mps + 68816;
                    System.out.println("current money per second is " + mps);

                } else if(input.matches("9") && money >= 18216000) { //same as last comment, but different numbers

                    money = money - 18216000;
                    mps = mps + 655776;
                    System.out.println("current money per second is " + mps);

                } else{ //if none of the above inputs are input, say something is wrong, either not enough money or not a chosen valid input
                    System.out.println("you don't have enough money for that!");
                }//end else

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }//end catch


        }//end while true loop
    }//end string
```

ps: it was fun playing playing cookie clicker in the terminal.

Comment: thanks man! I thought I'd already tried that, but I guess I didn't.